# Input string was not in a correct format. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am doing a validation when the Value of Budget display is less than the amount that Cost Display the Submit Button will be hidden. But I am getting an error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Below is my code

---

```
void GetInfo(int ID)
{
    var cost = decimal.Parse(txtCost.Text);
    var budget = decimal.Parse(txtBudget.Text);

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProjectID, ClientID, Name, Description, Location, DateStarted, " +
            "DateEstFinished, Budget - ActualCost AS Total, ActualCost, Status FROM Projects WHERE ProjectID=@ProjectID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ID);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ltID.Text = dr["ProjectID"].ToString();
                ltName.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
                ddlTypes.Text = dr["ClientID"].ToString();
                txtName.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
                txtDescription.Text = dr["Description"].ToString();
                txtLocation.Text = dr["Location"].ToString();
                DateTime dateStarted = DateTime.Parse(dr["DateStarted"].ToString());
                txtDateStarted.Text = dateStarted.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
                txtStart.Attributes.Add("min", dateStarted.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                DateTime dateFinish = DateTime.Parse(dr["DateEstFinished"].ToString());
                txtDateFinish.Text = dateStarted.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");

                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                bool validStart = DateTime.TryParse(txtStart.Text, out start);

                if (validStart)
                    txtFinish.Attributes.Add("min", start.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                txtBudget.Text = dr["Total"].ToString();
                txtCost.Text = dr["ActualCost"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
            if (budget >= cost)
            {
                btnSubmit.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("~/Projects/Default.aspx");
        }

}
```

---

Comment: In which line, its giving error?

Comment: Which value this `txtBudget.Text` has?

Comment: And `txtCost.Text` as well

Comment: txtBudget and txtCost values are decimal(18, 2) in the database

Comment: No, before submitting which values user has enter in these both text boxes?

Comment: [Use the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx), Luke!

Comment: There should be numeric values in both `txtBudget` and `txtCost`

Comment: Most likely your problem is here `DateTime dateStarted = DateTime.Parse(dr["DateStarted"].ToString());`. Is your date stored as a string? If so **why**? They should be stored as a date value. Are empty dates returned as an empty string or null? If the problem is not here it is likely to be in one of the date formatting strings. You haven't given enough info. You should be able to tell what line is affected with a line number, or put a break point and debug, watching values.

Comment: txtBudget and txtCost has a type="number" in the source code.

Comment: The All Date has a datatype value of "datetime" with a type="date" in the source code

Comment: ..and are you sure all dates are valid in your database?

Comment: oh Sorry I saw a one of my Date has no type="date" in the source code. Thanks Jon P.

Now I am getting an error on "var cost = decimal.Parse(txtCost.Text);" with the same error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Don't use asp controls like `txtCost` to pass around values. Use variables and I'd avoid anonymous types (`var`) and use the expected type instead. **Never** blindly parse. Use `tryParse` or at least check for null or empty strings first. Sounds like you are now trying to parse a string that can not be interpreted as a decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using:

```
if (Decimal.Parse(txtBudget.Text) >= Decimal.Parse(txtCost.Text))
{
    btnSubmit.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    btnSubmit.Visible = false;
}
```

and then declaring a var decimal

Comment: What if user enters "bla-bla-bla" into `txtBudget` field?

Comment: Agree with Dmitry ... you need to validate the entries ... but also ...btnSubmit.Visible = Decimal.Parse(txtBudget.Text) >= Decimal.Parse(txtCost.Text)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
Decimal budget;
Decimal cost;

if (!Decimal.TryParse(txtBudget.Text, out budget)) {
  btnSubmit.Visible = false; 
  //TODO: probably you have to show message that txtBudget has incorrect value
}
else if (!Decimal.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out cost)) {
  btnSubmit.Visible = false; 
  //TODO: probably you have to show message that txtCost has incorrect value
}
else {
  //TODO: you may find useful to check if cost < 0 or/and budget < 0 etc.
  btnSubmit.Visible = budget >= cost;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your problem will be in `DateTime` Conversion because if it will get
>   `blank` or `Null` value then it will give as above mentioned error so
>   do as below provided code example for your all code where you have
>   used `datetime`

```
if(dr["DateStarted"].ToString() != "")
{
   txtDateStarted.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateStarted"]).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
}
```